# 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<short>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm getting compilation error at this line :

```
 GridView1.Columns[9].FooterText
        = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
           select row.Field<Int16>("quantity"))
                       .Skip(GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize)
                       .Take(GridView1.PageSize).Sum()
                       .ToString();
```

In my Database table Quantity Declared as Smallint

When i build my Solution its throw this two Exception

```
Error   40  Instance argument: cannot convert from
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<short>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

 Error  41  `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<short>'` does not
 contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload
'System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>)'
 has some invalid arguments
```

How do i Solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sum() does not contain an overload that accepts a short (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb919210%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

You could always cast to int, then sum the casted collection.

```
GridView1.Columns[9].FooterText
    = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
       select row.Field<Int16>("quantity"))
                   .Skip(GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize)
                   .Take(GridView1.PageSize).Select(x => (int)x).Sum()
                   .ToString();
```